# simple rand() question

Tags: php, text, random, format, pad

I need a random 4 digit number

right now im using rand(1000,9999) that always gives me a 4 digit number but i eliminates 0000-0999 as possible results.

how do you pad a random number?

(also this is eventually going to be added to a string do i need to cast the int as a string?)

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In scripting languages like PHP, you don't have to cast in 99% of the cases.

Padding could be done using

```
sprintf("%04u", rand(0, 9999));
```

**Explanations**

the first argument of `sprintf` specifies the format

- `%` stays for the second, third, forth etc. argument. the first `%` gets replaced by the second argument, the second `%` by the third etc.
- `0` stays for the behaviour of filling with `0` to the left.
- `4` stays for "At least 4 characters should be printed"
- `u` stays for unsigned integer.

Comment: +1. Nice dissection of the format string. I always have to look them up :-)

Answer (score 6):

```
sprintf("%04d", rand(0,9999))
```

should do what you want

Comment: damn it. one second too late -.-

Comment: actually you have like a million rep points im going to give it to etan

Comment: Aww. I've hit the rep cap for today a few hours ago anyway. So whether it's 215 or 230 doesn't make much of a difference :-)

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty... how about doing:

```
rand(10000,19999)
```

and take the last four digits:

```
substr(rand(10000, 19999), 1, 4)
```

Comment: Smart! I must say. Thinking out of the box.

Comment: Although this will work, coming across this in code is going to make me pause and wonder what is going on.

Comment: @LFSR: You're absolutely right, which is why it's quick and "dirty".  :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
str_pad(mt_rand(0, 9999), 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Use mt_rand() instead of rand(), it's better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [str_pad()](http://php.net/str_pad) or [sprintf()](http://php.net/sprintf) to format your string:

```
$rand = rand(0, 9999);
$str1 = str_pad($rand, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$str2 = sprintf('%04u', $rand);
```